# I am trying to understand solid principles: does my class disrupt single responsibility

Tags: python, django

This is the class that I created. It works with Django models and stores some user states.
Do I need to divide it? Maybe some pattern I need to use?

```
class User:

    def __init__(self, telegram_id):
        self.telegram_id = telegram_id
        self.ids_cards_to_review = set()
        self.ids_of_created_cards = set()
        self.create_user_in_db()
        self._fill_ids_of_created_cards()
        self._fill_ids_cards_to_review_list()


    def create_user_in_db(self) -> None:
        logging.info(f'Creating user {self.telegram_id} in db')
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                user = UserModel.objects.create(telegram_id=self.telegram_id)
                user.save()
                logging.info(f'User {self.telegram_id} created in db')
        except IntegrityError:
            logging.info(f'User {self.telegram_id} already exists')

    def count_of_words_to_review(self) -> int:
        return len(self.ids_cards_to_review)

    def add_new_word(self, word_id: int) -> None:
        self._add_new_word_user_relation_in_db_as_word_to_review(word_id)
        self._add_id_card_in_ids_of_created_cards(word_id)
        self._add_id_card_in_review_list(word_id)

    def add_new_word_as_known(self, word_id: int) -> None:
        self._add_new_word_user_relation_in_db_as_known_word(word_id)
        self._add_id_card_in_ids_of_created_cards(word_id)

    def add_success_review_to_word(self, card_id: int) -> None:
        card = UserWord.objects.get(id=card_id)
        card.count_of_views += 1
        card.save()
        self._delete_id_card_from_review_list(card_id)

    def add_not_success_review_to_word(self, card_id: int) -> None:
        card = UserWord.objects.get(id=card_id)
        if card.count_of_views > 6:
            card.count_of_views = 3
            card.save()

    def get_new_word_id(self)-> int:
        last_user_card_id = sorted(self.ids_of_created_cards, reverse=True)[0]
        last_user_card = UserWord.objects.get(id=last_user_card_id)
        return last_user_card.word.id + 1

    def put_word_id_in_words_to_review_in_end_of_the_line(self, word_id: int) -> None:
        self.add_not_success_review_to_word(word_id)
        self._delete_id_card_from_review_list(word_id)
        self._add_id_card_in_review_list(word_id)

    def _create_new_word_user_relation_in_db(self, word_id: int, count_of_view: int) -> None:
        user = UserModel.objects.get(telegram_id=self.telegram_id)
        word = Word.objects.get(id=word_id)

        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                user_word = UserWord.objects.create(user=user, word=word, count_of_views=count_of_view, last_view=datetime.now())
                user_word.save()

        except IntegrityError:
            logging.info(f'User {self.telegram_id} already has card with id {word_id}')

        logging.info(f'User {self.telegram_id} created new card with id {word_id}')

    def _fill_ids_of_created_cards(self) -> None:
        user = UserModel.objects.get(telegram_id=self.telegram_id)
        cards = UserWord.objects.filter(user=user)

        if not cards:
            logging.info(f'User {self.telegram_id} has no cards')

        ids = {card.id for card in cards}
        logging.info(f'User {self.telegram_id} has cards with ids {ids}')
        self.ids_of_created_cards = ids

    def _fill_ids_cards_to_review_list(self) -> None:
        for card_id in self.ids_of_created_cards:
            card = UserWord.objects.get(id=card_id)
            if check_card_for_new_review(card):
                self.ids_cards_to_review.add(card_id)

    def _delete_id_card_from_review_list(self, word_id: int) -> None:
        try:
            self.ids_cards_to_review.remove(word_id)
        except KeyError:
            logging.info(f'User {self.telegram_id} has no card with id {word_id} in review list')

    def _add_id_card_in_review_list(self, word_id: int) -> None:
        self.ids_cards_to_review.add(word_id)

    def _add_id_card_in_ids_of_created_cards(self, word_id: int) -> None:
        self.ids_of_created_cards.add(word_id)

    def _add_new_word_user_relation_in_db_as_known_word(self, word_id: int) -> None:
        self._create_new_word_user_relation_in_db(word_id, 20)

    def _add_new_word_user_relation_in_db_as_word_to_review(self, word_id: int) -> None:
        self._create_new_word_user_relation_in_db(word_id, 0)
```

Comment: Why are your method's names so long? E.g. `_add_new_word_user_relation_in_db_as_word_to_review`, `put_word_id_in_words_to_review_in_end_of_the_line`.

Comment: What is your class intended to do regarding SOLID? Can you address each s8ngle claim of the acronym?

Comment: Also, please edit your title so that it describes what the code does, rather than your question about it. See [ask].